# Java Homework MaxSumTest

Tags: java, data-structures

I am currently attempting to revise a Java Homework program for my Data Structures class that displays the output of the MaxSumTest program in a table.

I've created four arrays, and placed them inside one of the loops that calculates the timing info. I am trying to populate each array with only the timing info for one algorithm. So each array would have 4 elements. However, every time I run my revision of the program, I get an out of bounds error.

[Here is the Original](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsj3/code/MaxSumTest.java)

The only method I revised is getTimingInfo. Here is my revision:

```
public static void getTimingInfo( int n, int alg )
{
    int [] test = new int[ n ];

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis( );;
    long totalTime = 0;



   //create an array for each Algorithm
    long[] alg4;
    long[] alg3;
    long[] alg2;
    long[] alg1;

    //allocate memory for 5 long ints 

    alg4 = new long[5];
    alg3 = new long[5];
    alg2 = new long[5];
    alg1 = new long[5];

   int i;
   int j;
   int index = 0;

   for( i = 0; totalTime < 4000; i++ )
   {
       for( j = 0; j < test.length; j++ )
           test[ j ] = rand.nextInt( 100 ) - 50;
    index = j;
       switch( alg )
       {
         case 1:
           maxSubSum1( test );
           break;
         case 2:
           maxSubSum2( test );
           break;
         case 3:
           maxSubSum3( test );
           break;
         case 4:
           maxSubSum4( test );
           break;
       }

       totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis( ) - startTime;

   }

    alg1[index] = totalTime * 1000 / i;
    alg2[index] = totalTime * 1000 / i;
    alg3[index] = totalTime * 1000 / i;
    alg4[index] = totalTime * 1000 / i;

    //Build first column of table
    System.out.println("Size of N Algorithms\t" + "250\t" + "2500\t" + "25000\t" + "250000");

    System.out.println("Alg #4\t" + alg4[0] + "\t" + alg4[1] + "\t" + alg4[2] + "\t" + alg4[3] + "\t" + alg4[4]);
    System.out.println("Alg #3\t" + alg3[0] + "\t" + alg3[1] + "\t" + alg3[2] + "\t" + alg3[3] + "\t" + alg3[4]);
    System.out.println("Alg #2\t" + alg2[0] + "\t" + alg2[1] + "\t" + alg2[2] + "\t" + alg2[3] + "\t" + alg2[4]);
    System.out.println("Alg #1\t" + alg1[0] + "\t" + alg1[1] + "\t" + alg1[2] + "\t" + alg1[3] + "\t" + alg1[4]);


    /*

    System.out.println( "Algorithm #" + alg + "\t"
         + "N = " + test.length
         + "\ttime = " + ( totalTime * 1000 / i ) + " microsec" );
    */


 }
```

Any advice or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: j will become equal to n eventually, and index is set to j, so if you specify n > 5, you will access alg out of its bounds, which is defined as 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I think that what you really want to do is call `getTimingInfo()` a number of times and then assign the results to a table, not change the internal workings of `getTimingInfo()`.

This requires that you define the arrays in which you will store the timing data OUTSIDE of `getTimingInfo()`, and then the only change inside of `getTimingInfo()` would be storing to that (already defined) array, rather than printing.

Comment: The original program outputs the results one per line. For example Algorithm 4 = xxx, Algorithm3 = xxx....  What I want to do is store the results of all of the times for each algorithm to their own array, then print them out in a tabular form.

Comment: My point was that you are collecting the data in the wrong place. The `getTimingInfo()` method does not test all of the algorithms at once. It only tests one algorithm (the one specified by the `alg` parameter) per call. Thus it doesn't make sense to create the arrays and print them out within the function--only one of the entries for the arrays is created with each call. The correct place to put this logic is in `main()`, where the loop to call `getTimingInfo()` multiple times is located.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My logic was totally off on this. I'm going to rewrite it with the array manipulation code in the main method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the lines that update the array elements be inside the inner loop?

```
alg1[index] = totalTime * 1000 / i;
alg2[index] = totalTime * 1000 / i;
alg3[index] = totalTime * 1000 / i;
alg4[index] = totalTime * 1000 / i;
```

You are assigning them outside the loop, where the value of `index` is 5, so it's out of bounds.

Comment: Couldn't put my finger on the fix, but knew it was related to that. n = j = index, so n > 4 causes a out of bound! Good eye :)

Comment: That is whereI originally had them but I was getting divide by zero errors on the first iteration where i was equal to zero.

Comment: It's actually the only place you can put them without getting index out of bounds. I don't know about the functionality of your program, but maybe you can divide by `i + 1`?

Answer (score 1):

```
long[] alg1;
alg4 = new long[5];
```

Can be better expressed as

```
long[] alg1 = new long[5];

maxSubSum3( test );
```

Is written nicer as

```
maxSubSum3(test);

int j;
int index = 0;
```

Actually do the same thing.

Just to pick a few points.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the alg4, alg3, alg2, and alg1 to size 5, not size 4 as you said you needed.